# How to print a file path in reverse order in Java?

Tags: java

I want to print the relative path of file/folder in reverse order.

```
IPath projectRelativePath = element.getProjectRelativePath();
```

the result is "src/abc/foldername".

But I want the result in reverse manner ie. foldername/abc/src.

Can someone help me here? Is there any JAVA API available for this?

Comment: Not sure of an API for this, but one way would be to split by `/` and then reverse the array.

Comment: yes that is the only way I know.

Comment: SO is not a code writing or translation service. You can show your attempt and ask about a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could do that by splitting the path by "/" and afterwards concatenating the tokens in reverse order.

Here is a code snippet:

```
    Path path = Path.of("this/that/folder");
    List<String> tokens = Arrays.stream(path.toString().split("/")).toList();
    StringBuilder newPath = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = tokens.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
       newPath.append(tokens.get(i));
       newPath.append("/");
    }
    System.out.println(newPath.toString());
```

Comment: That whole stream into list thing is a bit of an ugly wart in this. Just... go with the result of split, there's zero benefit to a list here. If you really wanted one, `List.copyOf(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

A `Stream` of the `Path` components could be used to reverse the components of a relative path, and also handles any platform using the appropriate file separator:

```
Stream.iterate(Path.of("src/abc/foldername"), Objects::nonNull, Path::getParent)
      .map(Path::getFileName).map(Path::toString)
   .collect(Collectors.joining(File.separator));
==> "foldername/abc/src"  (or foldername\abc\src on Windows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are using interface `IPath` from Eclipse Platform (not stated in your question, but seems reasonably likely).

From the [IPath documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIPath.html) we can see that we can get individual segments in reverse order like this:

```
for (int i = projectRelativePath.segmentCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(projectRelativePath.segment(i)); // or append to string etc.
}
```